# How would I perform this query in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
class ExternalUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    external_account_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

class ExternalFriends(models.Model):
    external_user = models.ForeignKey(ExternalUser)
    external_account_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

Suppose I first get all ExternalFriends:

```
all_friends = ExternalFriends.objects.all()
```

OK, now I have a query set.

How do I `SELECT * FROM ExternalUser WHERE external_account_id IN [ ...all_friends's external_account_ids... ]`?

What would be the Django equivalent?

Comment: Do you really need the "external_account_id" field on both models? As your ExternalFriends already relate to ExternalUser it could be sufficient to store the id on the ExternalUser model. That would also simplify your queries.

Comment: maybe: ExternalUser.objects.filter(external_friends__external_account_id__is_null=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can be done more efficiently but...

```
ExternalUser.objects.filter(external_account_id__in=[friend.id for friend in all_friends])
```

Comment: was hoping someone else could answer that! I think get just ids all_friends = ExternalFriends.objects.all().values('id') then replace frield.id with friend['id']

Comment: +1 IN clauses are not efficient in general, but your query is correct in this situation. How we got "all_friends" is the question to avoid IN, and make joins if possible.